# Google Script with Python example - GET Request - HTML result error

Tags: python, html, google-apps-script, get, google-apps-script-api

I'm trying to connect a Google spreadsheet via API GET request to receive some information from snov.io, but I am getting a HTML result instead of a JSON. The below Python code works, but the Google Appscript not. Any suggestions? Thank you :)

Python code - Working

```
params = {
  'access_token': token,
  'domain': site,
  'type': 'all',
  'limit': 100,
  'lastId': 0,
  }
res = requests.get('https://api.snov.io/v2/domain-emails-with-info', params=params)
return json.loads(res.text)
```

AppScript - not working - received HTML result

```
  'access_token': token,
  'domain': site,
  'type': 'all',
  'limit': 100,
  'lastId': 0,
    }

var url = 'https://api.snov.io/v2/domain-emails-with-info'
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {method: "get", payload: params, 'muteHttpExceptions': true}); 
var json = response.getContentText()
console.log(response.getContentText())
obj = JSON.parse(json)
result=obj.emails
return result
}
```

HTML Result :(

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>                body { background-color: #fff; color: #222; font: 16px/1.5 -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; }
                .container { margin: 30px; max-width: 600px; }
                h1 { color: #dc3545; font-size: 24px; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
                        <div class="container">
                    <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following python script to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    params = {
      'access_token': token,
      'domain': site,
      'type': 'all',
      'limit': 100,
      'lastId': 0,
      }
    res = requests.get('https://api.snov.io/v2/domain-emails-with-info', params=params)
    return json.loads(res.text)
  ```

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
var params = {
  'access_token': token,
  'domain': site,
  'type': 'all',
  'limit': 100,
  'lastId': 0,
};
var url = 'https://api.snov.io/v2/domain-emails-with-info';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?" + Object.entries(params).map(([k, v]) => k + "=" + v).join("&"), { method: "get", 'muteHttpExceptions': true });
```

- When `params` is used as the GET method at the request module of python, that is used as the query parameter. But, at the method of "UrlFetchApp.fetch" of Google Apps Script, when `params` is used to `payload`, it is automatically used as the POST method. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike the modified script worked like a charm! Thank you and have a great weekend.

Comment: @SKuan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.